# Загрузка видео через YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-android-api

Здравствуйте! Я являюсь разработчиком приложения для Android, в нашем приложении мы хотим добавить возможность загрузки видео длительностью 10-30 секунд, в котором пользователи могли бы рассказать о себе. Видео наших пользователей хотелось бы загружать на наш канал (чтобы не авторизовывать пользователя, а выполнять автоматический вход в наш аккаунт), привязанный к данному приложению. Существует ли возможность реализации такого функционала, и если такая возможность есть, хотелось бы узнать какие есть ограничения бесплатного использования и какие тарифы платного. А также вопрос, если пользователь загружает видео непристойного характера или не соответствующие требованиям YouTube, то как я понимаю, видео будет удаляться, но не будут ли накладываться какие-либо санкции на наш канал. Не хотелось бы потерять все видео из-за недобросовестного пользователя. Спасибо.

Я смог сделать загрузку видео, но только через авторизацию пользователя, также я нашел информацию о так называемом "сервисном аккаунте", возможно ли сделать описанный выше функционал через него?